# Adding notes/tasks not working in Google Assistant

Tags: google-assistant, notes

When I say "note to self" or "add a note" (or "note to self buy milk"), Google should be directing that command to one of the apps that accept note commands, including Todoist, Any.do, Keep, Gmail, etc.

However, on my primary personal account, commands never get directed anywhere except to what looks like some minimal built-in note service, and there's no way to change the default app.

[**Here is a video of the expected behavior**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pAzxekD4d4w) (using Google Assistant with a different account than my main personal account). Note that just "note to self" results in a response that displays an app icon that you can click on to change the default note app, as [described elsewhere on the web](https://www.guidingtech.com/change-note-app-google-assistant/).

The expected behavior is also what other people I've asked experience on their phones / on their own accounts, and is corroborated with [discussions elsewhere on the web](https://www.reddit.com/r/todoist/comments/6yhsnw/does_anyone_use_todoist_via_google_assistant/).

[**Here is a video of the problematic behavior**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uOf6vBXGN5E), when using Google Assistant on my main personal account.

**I've already tried a number of things**, including:

- Deleting all local data associated with the Google app and re-setting
  up Google Assistant.
- Resetting my default apps in the phone settings.
- Removing and re-adding my Google account to my phone entirely.

I *suspect* that this may have something to do with Google Home, since that minimal notes service seems to be associated with Google Home when I search the web for info on it.  It's not even listed as an available app in that first video.

Any ideas how to fix this? Thanks tremendously in advance!

(I'm also aware that—for Todoist at least—you can drop into a "[talk to Todoist](https://get.todoist.help/hc/en-us/articles/115000056165-How-can-I-use-Todoist-with-Google-Assistant-)" mode ([app listing page](https://assistant.google.com/services/a/uid/0000008b38c692dd?hl=en-US)) in Google Assistant, which is not what I'm asking about here—I just want to be able to fire off reminders in a single command, and also to apps other than Todoist.)